# How to define a user define data type in XML schema?

Tags: xml, xsd

I have defined two complex element types - Developer and App.

Developer childs - ID ,Name, Email

App childs - ID, Name, **Developer**

Here the **Developer** in App complex element refers to Developer/ID.

How to define this relationship in xml schema. I am using XML spy2013 editor.

I have tried specifying name in the declaration of simple type Developer->ID. And using this name in App->Developer datatype. But it gives error..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- edited with XMLSpy v2013 (x64) (http://www.altova.com) by Piyush (USC) -->
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified"          attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
<xs:element name="appinfo">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Developer">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:all>
                        **<xs:element name="ID">**
                            <xs:simpleType>
                                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                    <xs:length value="5"/>
                                    <xs:pattern value="[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][0-9][0-9][a-zA-Z]"/>
                                </xs:restriction>
                            </xs:simpleType>
                        </xs:element>
                        <xs:element name="Name">
                            <xs:simpleType>
                                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                    <xs:pattern value="([a-zA-Z])+"/>
                                </xs:restriction>
                            </xs:simpleType>
                        </xs:element>
                        <xs:element name="Email">
                            <xs:simpleType>
                                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                    <xs:pattern value="[^@]+@[^\.]+\..+"/>
                                </xs:restriction>
                            </xs:simpleType>
                        </xs:element>
                        <xs:element name="Company" type="xs:string"/>
                        <xs:element name="Website" type="xs:string"/>
                        <xs:element name="Phone">
                            <xs:simpleType>
                                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                    <xs:length value="13"/>
                                </xs:restriction>
                            </xs:simpleType>
                        </xs:element>
                    </xs:all>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="App">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:all>
                        <xs:element name="ID">
                            <xs:simpleType>
                                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                    <xs:length value="5"/>
                                    <xs:pattern value="[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][A-Z]"/>
                                </xs:restriction>
                            </xs:simpleType>
                        </xs:element>
                        <xs:element name="Name">
                            <xs:simpleType>
                                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                    <xs:pattern value="([a-zA-Z])+"/>
                                </xs:restriction>
                            </xs:simpleType>
                        </xs:element>
                        <xs:element name="Developer" ***type="xs:anySimpleType"/>***
                        <xs:element name="Price">
                            <xs:simpleType>
                                <xs:restriction base="xs:float">
                                    <xs:minInclusive value="0.00"/>
                                    <xs:maxInclusive value="6.99"/>
                                </xs:restriction>
                            </xs:simpleType>
                        </xs:element>
                        <xs:element name="TabletCompatible" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0"/>
                        <xs:element name="Category">
                            <xs:simpleType>
                                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                    <xs:enumeration value="Travel"/>
                                    <xs:enumeration value="Productivity"/>
                                    <xs:enumeration value="Game"/>
                                    <xs:enumeration value="Music"/>
                                    <xs:enumeration value="Education"/>
                                    <xs:enumeration value="Lifestyle"/>
                                </xs:restriction>
                            </xs:simpleType>
                        </xs:element>
                        <xs:element name="Platform">
                            <xs:simpleType>
                                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                                    <xs:enumeration value="Android"/>
                                    <xs:enumeration value="iOS"/>
                                    <xs:enumeration value="Blackberry"/>
                                </xs:restriction>
                            </xs:simpleType>
                        </xs:element>
                    </xs:all>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
            <xs:element name="AppStat">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:all>
                        <xs:element name="AppID" type="xs:anySimpleType"/>
                        <xs:element name="Statistics">
                            <xs:complexType>
                                <xs:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                    <xs:element name="Platform" type="xs:anySimpleType"/>
                                    <xs:element name="Downloads" type="xs:positiveInteger"/>
                                    <xs:element name="Rating">
                                        <xs:simpleType>
                                            <xs:restriction base="xs:float">
                                                <xs:minInclusive value="0.0"/>
                                                <xs:maxInclusive value="5.0"/>
                                            </xs:restriction>
                                        </xs:simpleType>
                                    </xs:element>
                                </xs:sequence>
                            </xs:complexType>
                        </xs:element>
                        <xs:element name="LastChecked" type="xs:date"/>
                    </xs:all>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Comment: I don't know who upvoted this question or why, but I'm downvoting it. If you write some code and it gives us an error, you should show us the code that you wrote and the error that it gave, then we can see where you went wrong. You mustn't be frightened or embarrassed about showing your coding attempts; the best way to learn is to subject your efforts to critical review by people with more experience of the technology you are learning.

Answer (score 18):

The way to use a common simple type for the developer id is to declare it as a named type at the beginning:

```
<xs:schema 
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
  elementFormDefault="qualified"          
  attributeFormDefault="unqualified">

  <xs:simpleType name="developerID">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:length value="5"/>
      <xs:pattern value="[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][0-9][0-9][a-zA-Z]"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

  . . .
```

and then use it:

```
 . . . 
    <xs:element name="Developer" maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:all>
          <xs:element name="ID" type="developerID">
 . . . 
    <xs:element name="App" maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:all>
          . . .
          <xs:element name="Developer" type="developerID"/>
```

But this is not enough to create a contraint so that `appinfo/App/Developer` can contain only one of the developers' ids declared in `appinfo/Developer/ID`. To do that is necessary to create a unique key definition using `xs:key` and reference it using `xs:keyref` (see [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317688)).

Here is the complete XSD:

```
<xs:schema 
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
  elementFormDefault="qualified"          
  attributeFormDefault="unqualified">

  <xs:simpleType name="developerID">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:length value="5"/>
      <xs:pattern value="[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][0-9][0-9][a-zA-Z]"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

  <xs:element name="appinfo">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Developer" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:all>
              <xs:element name="ID" type="developerID">
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Name">
                <xs:simpleType>
                  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:pattern value="([a-zA-Z])+"/>
                  </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Email">
                <xs:simpleType>
                  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:pattern value="[^@]+@[^\.]+\..+"/>
                  </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Company" type="xs:string"/>
              <xs:element name="Website" type="xs:string"/>
              <xs:element name="Phone">
                <xs:simpleType>
                  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:length value="13"/>
                  </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:all>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="App" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:all>
              <xs:element name="ID">
                <xs:simpleType>
                  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:length value="5"/>
                    <xs:pattern value="[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][A-Z]"/>
                  </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Name">
                <xs:simpleType>
                  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:pattern value="([a-zA-Z])+"/>
                  </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Developer" type="developerID"/>
              <xs:element name="Price">
                <xs:simpleType>
                  <xs:restriction base="xs:float">
                    <xs:minInclusive value="0.00"/>
                    <xs:maxInclusive value="6.99"/>
                  </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="TabletCompatible" type="xs:boolean" minOccurs="0"/>
              <xs:element name="Category">
                <xs:simpleType>
                  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:enumeration value="Travel"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="Productivity"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="Game"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="Music"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="Education"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="Lifestyle"/>
                  </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Platform">
                <xs:simpleType>
                  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:enumeration value="Android"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="iOS"/>
                    <xs:enumeration value="Blackberry"/>
                  </xs:restriction>
                </xs:simpleType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:all>
          </xs:complexType>
          <xs:keyref name="developerIDref" refer="developerID">
            <xs:selector xpath="."/>
            <xs:field xpath="Developer"/>
          </xs:keyref>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="AppStat">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:all>
              <xs:element name="AppID" type="xs:anySimpleType"/>
              <xs:element name="Statistics">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
                    <xs:element name="Platform" type="xs:anySimpleType"/>
                    <xs:element name="Downloads" type="xs:positiveInteger"/>
                    <xs:element name="Rating">
                      <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="xs:float">
                          <xs:minInclusive value="0.0"/>
                          <xs:maxInclusive value="5.0"/>
                        </xs:restriction>
                      </xs:simpleType>
                    </xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="LastChecked" type="xs:date"/>
            </xs:all>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:key name="developerID">
      <xs:selector xpath="Developer"/>
      <xs:field xpath="ID"/>
    </xs:key>
  </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```